# Idiomatic way to implement standard Unix behaviour of using STDIN if no files are specified on the command line?

Tags: raku

Is there a more elegant way of processing input coming from either the command line arguments or `STDIN` if no files were given on the command line? I'm currently doing it like this:

```
sub MAIN(*@opt-files, Bool :$debug, ... other named options ...) {
    # note that parentheses are mandatory here for some reason
    my $input = @opt-files ?? ([~] .IO.slurp for @opt-files) !! $*IN.slurp;

    ... process $input ...
}
```

and it's not too bad, but I wonder if I'm missing some simpler way of doing it?

Comment: Maybe lean on [`$*ARGFILES`](https://docs.raku.org/language/variables#$*ARGFILES)? Aiui, in `raku.d` or later, `$*ARGFILES` *inside* `MAIN` will be the same as `$*IN`. But *outside*, so presumably in, for example, `RUN-MAIN`, it'll be set to prospective-handles-to-be corresponding to each of the arguments on the command line interpreted as files, or to `$*IN` if the command line was empty. Anyhoo, I'm suggesting you read the doc I linked, and follow the "class documenation" link it provides.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd probably do two things to change this. I'd break up the ?? !! onto different lines, and I'd go for a full method chain:

```
sub MAIN(*@opt-files, Bool :$debug, ... other named options ...) {
    my $input = @opt-files 
                  ?? @opt-files».IO».slurp.join
                  !! $*IN.slurp;

    ... process $input ...
}
```

You can also map it by using `@opt-files.map(*.IO.slurp).join`

Edit: building on [ugexe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63659835/3646587), you could do

```
sub MAIN(*@opt-files, Bool :$debug, ... other named options ...) {

    # Default to $*IN if not files
    @opt-files ||= '-';

    my $input = @opt-files».IO».slurp.join

    ... process $input ...

}
```

Comment: It's true that the inputs are slightly different, but this is pretty standard Unix behaviour (e.g. `cat`). Using `join` is probably indeed more readable than `[~]`, thanks.

Comment: Thanks, the part after edit is the best solution IMO, I haven't realized I could just use `'-'` here. BTW, should it be `//=` rather than `||=`?

Comment: @VZ. Actually no, you have to use `||=` because the slurpy array will be defined (and `//`is defined-or) but empty (which is falsey).

Answer (score 11):

I would probably go for a `multi sub MAIN`, something like:

```
multi sub MAIN(Bool :$debug)
{
    process-input($*IN.slurp);
}

multi sub MAIN(*@opt-files, Bool :$debug)
{
    process-input($_.IO.slurp) for @opt-files;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I should have added that I actually used this initially, but decided to merge them together once I had more than one named option (I should have been more explicit about the `...` part), as I didn't want to duplicate the options and their `#=` descriptions.

Comment: One way to get around that (having multiple named options that are shared across multiple `MAIN`s) is to define them in a `proto MAIN` and process the shared behaviour there before passing on to the more specific methods defined as `multi`. Here's an example on a WIP project of mine: https://gitlab.com/jjatria/raket/-/blob/e1238be7d6d7989c711496f9f8459c611cc70739/scripts/rocket-bot#L17

Answer (score 2):

Something that I might expect to work is to set `@*ARGS` to the list of file names in the signature.
And then just use `$*ARGFILES`.

```raku
sub MAIN( *@*ARGS, Bool :$debug, ... other named options ...) {

    my $input = slurp; # implicitly calls $*ARGFILES.slurp()

    ... process $input ...
}
```

It doesn't work though.

---

You could get Rakudo to update `$*ARGFILES` by nulling it with a low-level null before you use it.

```raku
sub MAIN( *@*ARGS, Bool :$debug, ... other named options ...) {

    { use nqp; $*ARGFILES := nqp::null }

    my $input = slurp;

    ... process $input ...
}
```

But that is using an implementation detail that may change in the future.

---

A better way is to just directly create a new instance of IO::ArgFiles yourself.

You can even store it in `$*ARGFILES`. Then `slurp` on its own would slurp in all of the file contents.

```raku
sub MAIN( *@opt-files, Bool :$debug, ... other named options ...) {

    my $*ARGFILES = IO::ArgFiles.new( @opt-files || $*IN );

    my $input = slurp;

    ... process $input ...
}
```

Note that IO::ArgFiles is just an empty subclass of IO::CatHandle.
So you could write `IO::CatHandle.new( @opt‑files || $*IN )` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep the last sentence of your answer in mind, and it's useful to know, but I believe the idea with using `'-'` is even better/simpler (thanks @ugexe and @user0721090601!), so I'll use it in my next script.